# Conditional distribution from joint PMF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm stuck on starting this problem, if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

> The joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by

> $p(0,0)=0.5, p(0,1)=0.1, p(1,0)=0.2, p(1,1)=0.2$

Find the pmt of $X$ given that $Y = 0.$

Would it be something like $p(0)=0.5, p(1)=0.2$?

(side note, should pmt be pmf?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be pmf (probability mass function).

We have $\Pr(X=0\mid Y=0)=\frac{0.5}{0.5+0.2}$ and  $\Pr(X=1\mid Y=0)=\frac{0.2}{0.5+0.2}$.  You had the ratio right, but the conditional probabilities have to have sum $1$.